# How to select color with data-style-name?

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning JavaScript and I tried to select color by *data-style-name*. There are four colors with different *data-style-name* and *data-style-id*. I was wondering how to select a color with a *data-stye-name*.

For example: Change *data-style-name = "Black"* to *data-style-name = "Red"* with something like *document.GetElementByName("data-style-name").value = "Red";*

Thanks

```html
<li>
  <a class="" data-images="{&quot;detail_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/194602/ma/Xx_WYtPp-3g.jpg&quot;,&quot;zoomed_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/194602/zo/Xx_WYtPp-3g.jpg&quot;}" data-style-name="Washed Navy" data-style-id="30164"
    data-sold-out="true" data-description="null" href="/shop/sweatshirts/dirphu7gz/cey3obkfw" data-no-tubolink="data-no-tubolink"><img width="32" height="32" src="//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/194602/sw/Xx_WYtPp-3g.jpg" alt="Xx wytpp 3g"></a>
  <a class="" data-images="{&quot;detail_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/194600/ma/OggexK6HrvQ.jpg&quot;,&quot;zoomed_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/194600/zo/OggexK6HrvQ.jpg&quot;}"
    data-style-name="Washed Navy" data-style-id="30164" data-sold-out="true" data-description="null" href="/shop/sweatshirts/dirphu7gz/cey3obkfw?alt=0" data-no-tubolink="data-no-tubolink"><img width="32" height="32" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/194600/sw/OggexK6HrvQ.jpg" alt="Oggexk6hrvq"></a>
  <a class="" data-images="{&quot;detail_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/194601/ma/0YQtNT2tzbk.jpg&quot;,&quot;zoomed_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/194601/zo/0YQtNT2tzbk.jpg&quot;}"
    data-style-name="Washed Navy" data-style-id="30164" data-sold-out="true" data-description="null" href="/shop/sweatshirts/dirphu7gz/cey3obkfw?alt=1" data-no-tubolink="data-no-tubolink"><img width="32" height="32" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/194601/sw/0YQtNT2tzbk.jpg" alt="0yqtnt2tzbk"></a>
  <a class="" data-images="{&quot;detail_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/194603/ma/pFnGyYydRpU.jpg&quot;,&quot;zoomed_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/194603/zo/pFnGyYydRpU.jpg&quot;}"
    data-style-name="Washed Navy" data-style-id="30164" data-sold-out="true" data-description="null" href="/shop/sweatshirts/dirphu7gz/cey3obkfw?alt=2" data-no-tubolink="data-no-tubolink"><img width="32" height="32" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/194603/sw/pFnGyYydRpU.jpg" alt="Pfngyyydrpu"></a>
  <a class="" data-images="{&quot;detail_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/194604/ma/dHU0IW1cn6s.jpg&quot;,&quot;zoomed_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/194604/zo/dHU0IW1cn6s.jpg&quot;}"
    data-style-name="Washed Navy" data-style-id="30164" data-sold-out="true" data-description="null" href="/shop/sweatshirts/dirphu7gz/cey3obkfw?alt=3" data-no-tubolink="data-no-tubolink"><img width="32" height="32" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/194604/sw/dHU0IW1cn6s.jpg" alt="Dhu0iw1cn6s"></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Are you looking to change `data-style-name` all at once ? You current HTML shows all as `washed Navy`

Answer (score 3):

**SELECTION**

Select the first element with a `data-style-name` attribute

```
document.querySelector('[data-style-name]')
```

Select all the elements with `data-style-name` attributes

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-style-name]')
```

Select the first element with a `data-style-name` attribute that equals 'Washed Navy'

```
document.querySelector('[data-style-name="Washed Navy"]')
```

Select all the elements with `data-style-name` attributes that equal 'Washed Navy'

```
document.querySelectorA('[data-style-name="Washed Navy"]')
```

**MODIFIYING ATTRIBUTES**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Change the `data-style-name` attribute to `red` for one element (`querySelector` returns one element)

```
document.querySelector('[data-style-name="Washed Navy"]').dataset.styleName = 'red';
```

Change the `data-style-name` attribute to `red` for all elements (`querySelectorAll` returns a collection of elements)

```
const elts =document.querySelectorAll('[data-style-name]');
elts.forEach(element => element.dataset.styleName = 'red');
```

Comment: Welcome. edited my answer to show you how to properly change the data attributes as well

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
const anchor = document.querySelector('[data-style-name="Washed Navy"]');
anchor.setAttribute('data-style-name', 'red')
```